# Error upon adding a new node. "NotWritablePrimary: Not-primary error while processing 'find'"

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 node replica-set

Vm1 - Primary
10.1.0.2
Priority = 2

Vm2 - Secondary
10.1.0.3
Priority = 1

Now I am trying to add a new node (Vm3 10.1.0.4 - Secondary Priority = 0) based on Data folder from Secondary.
(I stopped the mongod on secondary, then create a snapshot)

Now when I add the Vm3 on my replica set when I check the mongod.log
here is the error:

{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-06T22:05:13.172+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22990,   "ctx":"conn268","msg":"DBException handling request, closing client connection","attr":{"error":"NotWritablePrimary: Not-primary error while processing 'find' operation  on 'investastock_ta' database via fire-and-forget command execution."}}

There is also an error that the node is too stale to use candidate as a sync source

Answer (score 1):

Already fixed. The copy should be from the PRIMARY and not from a SECONDARY node. No downtime needed in my end even if the PRIMARY node is running when I took a snapshot. Running on MongoDB 4.4